# What is the ideal location to go animal hunting for hides?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Nidoru, a now level 22 sneaky archer, for some reason loves to hunt animals in the wild to obtain their hides.

What is the ideal location for Nidoru to do her hunting?

Comment: Anywhere.. You can not walk across skyrim with out running into deer, cats, wolves and bears... Oh my.

Comment: Is there a place for example where I can find herds of deer? Or lots of bears?

Comment: I put a bit more specific information into an exact answer.

Comment: Haha, this is what I did for the few levels of skyrim, hunting deer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alrighty, might as well give a full answer.

First, the game is just filled with wild life all over (I know this because I am an assassin and wild life is some of the hardest targets to sneak up on, but its fun to try anyways).

I have never seen more than 2-3 deer/elk next to each other so nothing like a large herd. But I can say I have seen more wild life in the green areas of the game. The plains outside of whiterun and then from there to the west have always been filled with elk/deer, packs of wolves, small dens of bears and those sneaky saber cats that I only ever seem to find when they are biting me.

I have not seen as much wild life in the snowy areas. This may be because they shift to 'snow' or 'ice' versions for things like foxes and wolves while the deer/elk do not have an equalivelent snowy version of themselves. To that end E and NE of Whiterun seem a bit more baren when it comes to this. Also, to the NW over the mountains to where the swamps are, there is not as much wild life (I run into spiders, bugs and crabs up there more than anything else).

Remember that once you clear out any area you will have to wait for it to respawn (which happens faster if you are not in that area).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since you answered nicely I will just add this: go to north of Ivarstead and there will be a cave there with a bear guarding it, kill him and then enter it, inside will be another bear. the bear outside respawns and i'm not sure about the one inside.

Comment: @disponser Are you referring to the honey cave? I thought that was SE of Ivarstead?

Comment: @desaivv Hmm, Ill have to take a peek and see. I can one shot most animals so I have never really tried poisons on em. I just Steeeal their Sooouls! :)

Comment: If you've got the DB add-on, Solstheim's is practically bursting with horkers and netch.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer hunting bears, which can often be found in [caves](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Caves), like [Honeystrand](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Honeystrand_Cave) and [PinePeak](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pinepeak_Cavern).

Answer (score 1):

The mountains around Swindler's Den and along the river in the same area have a ton of deer/elk plus saber cats wandering around.

Answer (score 1):

If you are searching for just elk/deer/wolves, just go to Riverwood and hunt in their forest.

If you are looking for bears I would try caves.

Trolls and wolves are also usually near waterfalls, I think they are in tiny caves that you don't even need to enter.

Also if you have the Dragonborn DLC and can ride a dragon just go to a Dragon mountain place get on and go to a Winterhold like area and just kill everything because believe or not your dragon will find a lot of wolves elks and snowbears.

Answer (score 0):

The plains outside of Whiterun have a lot of animals, including mammoths if you think you can handle them.

Comment: I can kill them, but I don't think they have any hides.

Answer (score 0):

To the west of Whiterun is a place with a large campfire with some giants and some mammoths around it, if you're up for the challenge. I'm not sure if they will respawn after you kill them, though.

Comment: I can kill them, but I don't think they have any hides.

Comment: Oh, that's right they usually will give you a mammoth snout and a mammoth tusk but no hide. If you really need hide badly, you could kill some cows in town, but you'll get fined.

Answer (score 0):

If you go east of Windhelm you will run into Scacellum of Boethiah. There is a weird quest where you fight the cult members. Once you win they want you to sacrifice your follower. Anyway, keep going up the stairs, past where they want you to do the sacrifice and do some climbing/hopping up the slope to the left which does resemble a path. You will get to another path like slope. At the top of that slope you will find a cave with 3 bears. They will res-spawn after you kill them so you can keep coming back!

Answer (score 0):

I'd also add that there's a TON of bears and wolves on the roads southeast of the hot springs area, north of Shor's stone.

Answer (score 0):

Outside Whiterun is a great area, but also I would sneak everywhere you go and never fast travel. Always walk or ride a horse. It is more realistic and you can find game along the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hunt deer, go to Falkreath's jungle, there's a good place for hunting.

Answer (score 0):

I start from falkreath and walk toward whiterun and head west once I reach the stables. west north west from the stables. I seen two packs of 3 deer together west of whiterun somewhere and had a field day. another thing I can say is I like to patrol around the falkrun lake, I find more wildlife near shores, or atleast I like to think I do. so basically my route is from say hunters lodge and either around the lake or straight to white run, then west or north west from there. after my route is done I have about enough leather to make 120 strips and still have 60 leather to make bracers. I hope this helps. also I hunt wolves, deer/elk and foxes. if bears and cats pop up, bonus.

I'm reading about mammoths here too now. no mammoths give no hides.... but they should... they should yield 8 leather each. but they don't. if you kill a giant though I killed one before and it had multiple hides/pelts... they're not so hard if you're a vamp lord. i never played as a lycan.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the alchemy lab, (When your going to Ivanstead). You'll typically find 3 moose right at the very front. Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

I like to go outside Falkreath. Plenty of wildlife for me. And if you want to easily sneak up on an animal, on your way up to High Hrothgar read every single tablet and it will give you the Voice of the Sky. This allows you to be able to walk near animals without having them run away so its so much easier to sneak up on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go break into farms, guard houses, or any building you will most likely find a few hides or at least one.

Also i suggest walking to your missions so you come across more game.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to riften...you can get a quest from the werewolf people to go to a cave outside riften and kill a troll and it will be hiding some thing called a hunters bow which does a little more damage to amimals ...mark it and go to the top of the cliff right above it(its in a cliff shelf)there are always two full grown deer right there along with two skin traders and the deer respawn also the place the bow was looks bad ass and of you enjoy wildlife its worth the werewolf drama...and its there without the quest if you realy dont want the guilding experience" brother" direclty between a dragon post that is in a deserted mine and the entrance to the uderground where ulric was captured

Answer (score -2):

I just wander around white run and head across skyrim on foot usually finding giant camps and lots of rabbits and fox. I walk back to white run then sell all of my junk to the guy who sells meats or cook it to keep, usually I save hides and pelts for smithing.

P.s. I just use a really weak bow on mammoths to get my archery high

Comment: Srry I go on god mode for that in computer